# What is your favorite bug/issue tracking system? And why?

Tags: bug-tracking

What is your favorite bug/issue tracking system? And why?

(Please answer this question only if you have used at least three different [bug tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system) systems for quite a long time. And please mention these systems as well.)

Comment: Is this different from my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use

Comment: Could you please add the "subjective" tag?

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate question it's darn close.  Downvoted.

Answer (score 9):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz) is actually great, as it's:

- simple to use
- intuitive
- integrates well
- featureful

Comment: And there is a special free single user / startup company license too (I think!)

Comment: @Ady - I'm looking at this as objectively as I can, and it's actually solid software with an excellent interface.

Comment: an excellent interface? google code has an excellent interface. FogBugz is bizarre, because I love reading Joels articles on UI design, but find his produces UIs appalling. Including stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Galwegian. My intention was not to suggest you were not being objective, simply an attempt (and fail) at dry wit.

Answer (score 8):

[Trac!](http://trac.edgewall.org) It's so nicely integrated with [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion). We just love it.

Comment: I used to work with Trac but I found it a hard to configure and maintain. Lack of Git support at the time made me switch to redmine. I find Redmine to be even better than Trac and easier to use and maintain.

Answer (score 8):

[Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) gets my vote. It is flexible and quick and has good integration with source control. It also has sub tasks, good categorisation, and configurable work flows.

Answer (score 3):

We just went through the rather time consuming process of reviewing many (perhaps ten?) issue tracking systems to replace [GForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GForge) which was getting in our way more than assisting. We considered free and commercial systems.

To be frank, I was disappointed with *all* of the systems we reviewed. There's plenty of room for improvement in this domain.

Many of them had poor interfaces ([OnTime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnTime), [JIRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA), [Bugzilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla)). Generally, our engineers were OK with this, but it's important for our project managers, system integrators and *customers* to be presented with an interface that is clear and aesthetically pleasing.

I was surprised to find that *very few* supported nested sub-issues. In the software world it is, of course, very common to break down a task (an issue or a new feature) into smaller components and assign them to different people. However, most systems couldn't do that - or couldn't do it well.

Some systems were very powerful and configurable but practically *required* third-party extensions or plugins to make them useful. I really liked the flexibility of JIRA and [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) for example, but we would have had to invest considerable time to configure the systems to make them pretty or more functional.

Naturally, they're not the only features we were concerned with, but this post is already getting too long!

Of course, your requirements are going to be different to ours - I encourage you to figure out what you require and investigate thoroughly.

[FogBugz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz), [JIRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA) and [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) were on our short list and they all had some great features. But in the end they were beaten by a product that - to me - was previously unknown: [VisionProject](http://www.visionproject.se/).

VisionProject is attractive and strikes a good balance between powerful and easy to use.  The only downside we're seeing at the moment is that their new (since v4.0) Ajax-y interface has been a little buggy. However, we've had multiple bugfixes overnight and sometimes within a couple of hours - kudos to their über-responsive development team.

We're still putting the system under trial and, although not perfect, it's comparing extremely favourably against all the other contenders.

Comment: I assume you are still using Vision Project ? Now that it's in version 5...how do you like it now? Does it integrate well to your source control and continuous integration server?

Comment: You might be interested in this one as well:

http://countersoft.com/products/gemini.aspx

Comment: @ShaChris23 Thanks, I'll take a look at Gemini. We did go with Vision Project but we're still at 4.1 as we wait for a breather in development before upgrading. It's working out very well - nice to use - and 5.0 looks impressive.  Haven't yet integrated it to our SCM and CI system.

Answer (score 3):

[Redmine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmine). It is:

1. Open source
2. [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) enabled
3. Email interface
4. [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) integration
5. Integrated wiki
6. Configurable trackers, workflow, and roles
7. RSS and email notifications

I have used [JIRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA) (too hard), [Bugzilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla) (too rubbish) and [FogBugz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz) (too expensive), and I think Redmine is fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

[Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server), though it's a little larger than just a bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

[Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) or [FogBugz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz) are looking pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

We adopted [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) because:

1. It's rather easy to install: if you follow exactly the setup instructions, it works, and this isn't a common situation!
2. It's extremely simple to use
3. It's per-project customizable (components, ticket types, severity, versions,...)
4. Has a flexible/customizable report section
5. Has an integrated wiki

But for us it has a big lack: CVS support. But we adopted it, because this isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using [Bugtracker.net](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) for awhile now.

It's good and the price (free) is right.

Some of my favorite features (From the site):

- Sending and receiving emails is integrated with the tracker, so that the email thread about a bug is tracked WITH the bug.
- Allows incoming emails to be recorded as bugs. So, for example, an email from your customer could automatically be turned into a bug/ticket in the tracker.
- Allows you to attach files and screenshots to bugs. There is even a custom screen capture utility [screenshot] that lets you take a screenshot, annotate it, and post it as a bug with just a few clicks. (inspired by Fogbugz)
- Add your own custom fields.
- Subscribe to email notifications that tell you whenever any bug has been added or changed. Or change your settings so you only get notified about the bugs you care about.

Comment: It's written in C#, if you want to tweak the code. Has nice Subversion integration. You can "brand" its look your way and put it on a public server.  It's heavily inspired by FogBugz, but more open and customizable. Info and demo at http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html

Answer (score 1):

I have [a page of links to discussions just like this](http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/2007/10/Links-to-other-comparisons-of-issue-trackers.aspx), where people have compared bug/issue trackers side by side and then have made a choice of the one they like best. There's no single tracker that consistently wins these competitions.

Of the open source ones, [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) ([Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)), [Redmine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmine) ([Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)), [Mantis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_Bug_Tracker) ([PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)), and my own [BugTracker.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BugTracker.NET) ([C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)) all have their fans, but I think with the open source ones, there is a tendency to pick the technology as well as the application. [FogBugz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz) and [JIRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA) seem to be the most popular commercial ones.

Answer (score 1):

[Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/)

It's free to use, incredibly simple and usable. 
Enforces Agile development cycle instead of being bloated by "configure everything to conform your development process".

Answer (score 0):

[Bugzilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla) is not too bad.

Bugzilla is very adaptable to various situations. Known uses
currently include IT support queues, systems administration
deployment management, chip design and development problem
tracking (both pre-and-post fabrication), and software and
hardware bug tracking for luminaries such as Red Hat, NASA,
Linux-Mandrake, and VA Systems. Combined with systems such
as [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System), Bonsai, or [Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce) SCM, Bugzilla provides a
powerful, easy-to-use solution to configuration management
and replication problems.

Bugzilla can dramatically increase the productivity and
accountability of individual employees by providing a
documented workflow and positive feedback for good
performance. How many times do you wake up in the morning,
remembering that you were supposed to do something today,
but you just can't quite remember? Put it in Bugzilla, and
you have a record of it from which you can extrapolate
milestones, predict product versions for integration, and
follow the discussion trail that led to critical decisions.

Ultimately, Bugzilla puts the power in your hands to improve
your value to your employer or business while providing a
usable framework for your natural attention to detail and
knowledge store to flourish.

Comment: Quoting sales-speak directly is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I like VersionOne (www.versionone.com). It is good if you are using one of the Agile processes (e.g. Scrum). You can manage all your features and tasks in addition to managing all the defects. There is a decent defect lifecycle defined, it has an available API, can be integrated with CVS and there exists an Outlook Add-in. There are many things in it that can still improve, but overall it is a good system for defect management if you are using agile methods.

Comment: VersionOne is great if you're a project manager, but not so great for developers. The heavy use of popup windows and the fact that you have to scroll around or click through tabs to find all the info on a story or defect makes it painful to use. A good usability review would probably do wonders.